# Multiple page navigation through routing

Tags: shell, xamarin.forms

I need to navigate to a page in a stack through routing but it is not navigating correctly as it is still remembering the existing Shell Navigation State.

I need examples or info on how to setup navigation like this. It should navigate like a wizard forward and backward or like breadcrumbs in a page.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to implement page navigation by using shell, You can refer to this linked article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation.
To achieve page navigation through the shell, First, configure the routing of the web page that needs to be redirected, like `Routing.RegisterRoute("page2", typeof(Page2))`.
You can use `Shell.Current.GoToAsync()` if you want to realize the page jump backward.
You can use `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..")` if you want to realize the page jump forward.

This is an example of page navigation jump:

1.Create three pages.

2.Create a shell page:

```
    <Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:App8"
        x:Class="App8.ShellPage">
        <ShellContent Title="Page1"
                      Icon="tupian.jpg"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Page1}"  />
    </Shell>
```

3.Set routing information on the shell page to bind three pages:

```
    public ShellPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute("page2", typeof(Page2));
        Routing.RegisterRoute("page3", typeof(Page3));
        Routing.RegisterRoute("page1", typeof(Page1));
    }
```

4.Add jump and back buttons to three pages(xaml):

```
  <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Page1!" FontSize="Large"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="click to page2"></Button>
        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked_1" Text="click to page3"></Button>
        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked_2"  Text="go back"></Button>
  </StackLayout>
```

5.Create three pages and add a jump button:

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Jump method
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("/page2");
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("/page3");
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Jump back method
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand how to do the navigation with routing. The problem I am facing is paging with multiple routes  in the following kind of relationship. Parent -> Children -> Child - Child Items - Item Details. How do I register routes and/or navigate to them in this way?

Comment: @GANDA1F You could try to use  `await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page());` when you want to open a new page.